# Replacement rule within a iteration with a new replacement needed at each step

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, iterators

I am trying to do a For iteration where at each step, the code solve an equation and use the result for the next step. Nevertheless, I am struggling with the replacement rules that I need to use.

I worked out the three first steps by hand. I edited the question to do it an only one parameter problem. Here resulttab is the table in which I want to keep my results, while C[k] are the coefficients I am searching for. I am going to iterate on k. My function Funct is a polynomial in  C[k]. This is not the real form since it involve a complete evaluation of another function into it but for the purpose of my question, I think that the following definition of funct is suitable.

```
funct[n_] := Sum[If[i == 0, c[0], i*c[i]], {i, 0, n}]
In[231]:= funct[3]
Out[231]= c[0] + c[1] + 2 c[2] + 3 c[3]

c0[k_] := Sum[n1^i, {i, 0, k}]
```

Now, at each step in n, I will compare the result with a symbolic expression that I have, called C0[1,1,0]. Those results are polynomials in $n_1$, where $n_1$ is constant. Therefore, comparing funct[1] with the first result will allow me to fix c[1]. Then funct[2] will depend on both c[1] and c[2] but as I know c[1], I  will be able to fix directly c[2] etc... . So the first step of the iteration is

```
resulttab[[1]] = c[0] /. (Solve[funct[0] == c0[0], c[0]][[1]])
```

This fixes

```
resulttab[[1]] = 1
```

resulttab and c have different indices since I have a symbolic c[0] while resulttab indexation starts at 1. The second step in the process is then

```
 resulttab[[2]] = c[1] /. (Solve[(funct[1] /. c[0] -> resulttab[[1]]) == c0[ 1], 
 c[1]][[1]])
```

. The third step would then be

```
resulttab[[3]] = c[2] /. (Solve[(funct[2] /. {c[1] -> resulttab[[2]], 
     c[0] -> resulttab[[1]]}) == c0[2], c[2]][[1]])
```

Now the problem I have is the following. At each step I am going to need an extra replacement rule of the form c[j]->resulttab[[j+1]] in order to automatize the resolution. In the end, the goal would be to have a function where I give the order up to which I want to go and that do this process up to the specified order.

Is there a convenient way to do it? Also using another method since mine seems somehow not very optimized.

Comment: Since the first two parameters in C and SC are staying constant, your example would be easier to read if you removed them. Provide a simple one-parameter version for people to work on and make it complete (ie include  a definition for Funct). Also it's advisable to use lower-case letters for symbols, to avoid potential conflict with built-ins. For example `C` is a built-in.

Comment: Agree with **Simon Wood**, we sure need the definition of `Funct` to be added to your query.

Comment: I edited the question with a definition of funct, and I did a one-parameter problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
funct[n_] := Sum[If[i == 0, c[0], i*c[i]], {i, 0, n}]

c0[k_] := Sum[n1^i, {i, 0, k}]

sols = {};

Do[
 AppendTo[sols, Solve[(funct[i] /. sols) == c0[i], c[i]][[1, 1]]],
 {i, 0, 4}
]

sols
```

> ```
> {c[0] -> 1, c[1] -> n1, c[2] -> n1^2/2, c[3] -> n1^3/3, c[4] -> n1^4/4}
> ```

If you permit direct assignments to `c[x]` this could also be written without `sols`:

```
Table[Set @@ Solve[funct[i] == c0[i], c[i]][[1, 1]], {i, 0, 4}]
```

> ```
> {1, n1, n1^2/2, n1^3/3, n1^4/4}
> ```

After which these definitions exist:

```
?c
```

> ```
> Global`c
>
> c[0]=1
>
> c[1]=n1
>
> c[2]=n1^2/2
>
> c[3]=n1^3/3
>
> c[4]=n1^4/4
> ```

---

Here is a somewhat different approach that you may consider.

First built a list of all your equations using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html):

```
eqs= 
 Table[
   funct[i] == c0[i],
   {i, 0, 4}
 ]
```

> ```
> {c[0] == 1,
>  c[0] + c[1] == 1 + n1,
>  c[0] + c[1] + 2 c[2] == 1 + n1 + n1^2,
>  c[0] + c[1] + 2 c[2] + 3 c[3] == 1 + n1 + n1^2 + n1^3, 
>  c[0] + c[1] + 2 c[2] + 3 c[3] + 4 c[4] == 1 + n1 + n1^2 + n1^3 + n1^4}
> ```

Then make a list of the variables you wish to solve for using [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
vars = Array[c, 5, 0]
```

> ```
> {c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}
> ```

Finally [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) using the option `Backsubstitution -> True`

[image]

```
result = Reduce[eqs, vars, Backsubstitution -> True]
```

> ```
> c[0] == 1 && c[1] == n1 && c[2] == n1^2/2 && c[3] == n1^3/3 && c[4] == n1^4/4
> ```

Use [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html) if needed:

```
ToRules[result]
vars /. ToRules[result]
```

> ```
> {c[0] -> 1, c[1] -> n1, c[2] -> n1^2/2, c[3] -> n1^3/3, c[4] -> n1^4/4}
>
> {1, n1, n1^2/2, n1^3/3, n1^4/4}
> ```

Comment: @Ezareth You are welcome.  If this answer is fully satisfactory please consider [Accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) it.  If it is not let me know how it might be improved.

Comment: @Ezareth I added a second method to my answer for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a function that takes and returns the solutions of the previous steps then you can use [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html).

```
findSol[sols_, n_] :=
 Append[sols,
  c[n] ->
   (c[n] /. First@Solve[(funct[n] /. sols) == c0[n], c[n]])
  ]
```

`findSol` takes the list of solutions, `sols`, performs the [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), and returns the previous solutions and the one just solved.

Next use `findSol` in `Fold` over the indices you want to solve for.

```
res = Fold[findSol, {}, Range[0, 4]]
```

> ```
> {c[0] -> 1, c[1] -> n1, c[2] -> n1^2/2, c[3] -> n1^3/3, c[4] -> n1^4/4}
> ```

Hope this helps.